# Jquery - Add and remove fields dynamically - How to do it without repeating code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, scope

I am implementing a "JQuery add/remove input fields" solution:
I need to use some JQuery plugins to make everything work. For example I use a Datepicker, SelectPicker and Autosize..
So, for the markup that's already there (without the ADD functionality) this code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.autosize').autosize();      
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();
    $('.datetimepickaa').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false
    });
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

    // Remove the specific row
    $("button.removee").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".conteiner").remove();
    });
});
```

The problem is that when I try to add the ADD functionality, the jquery plugins don't work for the new elements, so I have to repeat the calls inside the add code to make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.autosize').autosize();      
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();
    $('.datetimepickaa').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false
    });
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

    // Remove the specific row
    $("button.removee").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".conteiner").remove();
    });

    // ADD FUNCTIONALITY
    $("#add").click(function() {

        var row = '\
               <div class="form-group conteiner">\
                   <div class="row">\
                       <div class="col-md-2">\
                           <label for="date">Date:</label>\
                           <div class="input-group date datetimepickaa"  id="datetimepickerloop" data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD">\
                               <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepickaa" placeholder="Enter the date..." data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD" />\
                               <span class="input-group-addon">\
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>\
                               </span>\
                           </div>\
                       </div>\
                       <div class="col-md-9">\
                           <label for="notes">Notes:</label>\
                           <textarea class="form-control autosize" id="" name=""></textarea>\
                       </div>\
                       <div style="" class="col-md-1">\
                           <button type="button" class="removee btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right" style="margin-top:25px">\
                               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete\
                           </button>\
                       </div>\
                   </div>\
               </div>';

        $("#wrapper").append(row);

        // REPETITION OF THE CODE ABOVE!!!!!!   //////////////////////////////
        $('.autosize').autosize();      
        $('input, textarea').placeholder();
        $('.datetimepickaa').datetimepicker({
            pickTime: false
        });
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

        // Remove the specific row
        $("button.removee").click(function(){
            $(this).closest(".conteiner").remove();
        }); 

    });

});
```

Do you have any clue on how to do that the best way without repeting any code?

Thank's in advance!!

Comment: maybe try using clone instead?

Comment: Wrap code logic inside function and then call it when needed. Beware to not bind multiple click handlers for same element. For event handlers, looks like you should use delegation instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract them into a function and call that function?

```
function initializeThings()
{
$('.autosize').autosize();      
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();
    $('.datetimepickaa').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false
    });
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
 // Remove the specific row
    $("button.removee").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".conteiner").remove();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

initializeThings();



// ADD FUNCTIONALITY
$("#add").click(function() {

    var row = '\
           <div class="form-group conteiner">\
               <div class="row">\
                   <div class="col-md-2">\
                       <label for="date">Date:</label>\
                       <div class="input-group date datetimepickaa"  id="datetimepickerloop" data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD">\
                           <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepickaa" placeholder="Enter the date..." data-date-format="YYYY/MM/DD" />\
                           <span class="input-group-addon">\
                               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>\
                           </span>\
                       </div>\
                   </div>\
                   <div class="col-md-9">\
                       <label for="notes">Notes:</label>\
                       <textarea class="form-control autosize" id="" name=""></textarea>\
                   </div>\
                   <div style="" class="col-md-1">\
                       <button type="button" class="removee btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right" style="margin-top:25px">\
                           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete\
                       </button>\
                   </div>\
               </div>\
           </div>';

    $("#wrapper").append(row);

    initializeThings();

});
```